# Notification from FaceTime won't disappear!

Tags: mac, notifications, facetime

I have a notification on my MacBook that won't disappear.

My FaceTime app has a notification that wont disappear without me going into settings and clicking the badge icon. I want to delete the notification, not disable the badge icon, yet nothing works.

I've tried deleting all the recent and missed calls on my app and restarting it. It's not found in the Notification Center on the right (which opens when you click the 3 bars icon in the top right corner of the Menu Bar).

What do I do?

Answer (score 6):

What fixed it for me was to open up FaceTime and simply Quit out of it.

Answer (score 2):

This usually *(not always)* happens when there is still a missed call somewhere.  See if this helps:

1. Go to FaceTime → Preferences
2. Uncheck the box ‘Calls from this phone’
3. Ensure that only the correct phone number is listed there (and not some other family member)
4. Close Preferences and delete any Audio or Video calls listed on the left side

   Sometimes there's missed Audio calls and that causes the badge to appear.

Answer (score 2):

I've found say of clearing the badge by updating the database backing FaceTime on the Mac. [This detailed blog post I wrote](http://wp.me/p5uuGM-7n)  detailing the steps.

In essence, there is an SQLite db in `~/Library/Application Support/CallHistoryDB`, with a table called `ZCALLRECORD` which holds the read state, from which the badge is generated. The column name is `ZREAD`. Updating the value in this column to `1`, followed by a logout and login, should clear the badge.

Comment: This assumes that you want to otherwise keep the call history or data which exists for Facetime. If you do not, you can delete the directory (or better yet, rename it, in case you need to restore it).

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me when I received a call from my phone. The notification appeared on my computer, but I canceled the call from my phone. This is how I got rid of the tenacious notification:

1. Quit FaceTime app
2. Open Terminal (⌘ + Spacebar and type 'Terminal')
3. Run this command: `killall NotificationCenter`

Should do the trick!