# FaceTime call log delete

Tags: macos, facetime, logs

How do I delete facetime calls from my Mac?  Since the Sierra OS update I can not delete calls. I used to highlight then delete.

Comment: I couldn't say with certainty for Sierra, however, for El Capitan, the call data is stored in the `` directory. If the directory exists in Sierra, it may be worth renaming it, logging out and back into ~OS X~ \*ahem\* _macOS_, and making sure that worked.

However, given that I don't know if the data is synchronized with iCloud, there is a chance that the data could return. If so, editing the `ZCALLRECORD` file (it's an sqllite3 database file) may work. Some starter information can be found in my answer to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/284618)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Systems Preferences - Mouse and activate Secondary Click. This allows you to right click on your mouse.

After that, highlight the call you want to delete and right click your mouse. You will then be able to delete one or all calls.

Comment: You can also replicate this function with the built-in Mac keyboard function: CONTROL + CLICK